# Error "administrator has limited the number of items you can open simultaneously" when looping to sort mailitems

Tags: vba, sorting, outlook

When I loop over a folder with more than 1000 mails I get this error.
[image]

```vb
Function SortMailboxOnDate(mailbox As Outlook.folder) As Collection
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim Temp As Outlook.MailItem
    Set SortMailboxOnDate = New Collection

    For Each mail In mailbox.Items
        SortMailboxOnDate.Add mail
    Next
    
    'sorting collection from newest to oldest
    For i = 1 To SortMailboxOnDate.Count
        Dim bericht1 As Outlook.MailItem
        Set bericht1 = SortMailboxOnDate.Item(i)
        
        For j = i + 1 To SortMailboxOnDate.Count
            Dim bericht2 As Outlook.MailItem
            Set bericht2 = SortMailboxOnDate.Item(j)
            
            If bericht1.ReceivedTime < bericht2.ReceivedTime Then
                Set Temp = bericht2
                SortMailboxOnDate.Item(j) = bericht1
                SortMailboxOnDate.Item(i) = Temp
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
End Function
```

I tried setting bericht1 and bericht2 to nothing at the end of the loops but still the same error.

Comment: Drop `mail`, use an indexed loop for the `.Add`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looping over all items in the folder is *not really a good idea*:

```
For Each mail In mailbox.Items
```

If you need to sort out the collection of items in the folder you can use the [Sort](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.items.sort) method of the `Items` class which sorts the collection of items by the specified property. So, all your code is equal to the following single line of code:

```
myItems.Sort "ReceivedTime"
```

Note, the items are not sorted in the Outlook view in that case, only the collection.

Also don't keep Outlook object references in any collections, that may lead to problems like shown on your screenshot. Instead, you can use the `EntryID` property values and when required use the [NameSpace.GetItemFromID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.getitemfromid) method which returns a Microsoft Outlook item identified by the specified entry ID (if valid).

Answer (score 0):

`For each` loops keep all collection items references until the loop exits. Change the loop

```
For Each mail In mailbox.Items
   SortMailboxOnDate.Add mail
Next
```

to

```
set items = mailbox.Items
for i = 1 to items.Count
  set mail = items(i)
  SortMailboxOnDate.Add mail 
  set mail  = Nothing
next
```

.